# Why when I remove key from SharedPreference the second checkbox that i use it on does not respond properly?

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

everyone! I am working on an app that needs to setChecked and disable the checkbox after it is clicked. I used SharedPreferences, however, the second checkbox does not get setChecked and disabled although I call the same function on both checkboxes. Please help

```
CheckBox P2106;
CheckBox MP2106;

private SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_general_route);

    P2106 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_p2106);
    MP2106 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_mp2106);

    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor = pref.edit();

    TestCheck(P2106);
    TestCheck(MP2106);

public void TestCheck(CheckBox checkBox){
    if(pref.contains("checked") && pref.getBoolean("checked", false) == true){
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
        checkBox.setEnabled(false); //IMPORTANT
        editor.remove("checked").commit();
        editor.apply();

    }else{
        checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }


    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                editor.putBoolean("checked", true);
                editor.apply();
                Intent move = new Intent(GeneralRoute.this, ScanTest.class);
                startActivity(move);
            }else {
                editor.putBoolean("checked", false);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: no answer you receive here will be different because you've added android studio to the title or to the tags, unless you're asking about a feature of the IDE itself, you don't need to mention android studio

Comment: your code looks very complicated and confusing, probably why you're struggling with it so much. why do you only have `checked` in shared prefs, why not have a different variable based on which checkbox was actually checked, ie: checked1, checked2

Comment: the number of checkboxes can change, I need a rule for all

Comment: to debug this is going to be a recursive nightmare, because there's going to be no value called `checked` for the first checkbox, then there will be one for the second one, and all of this before a user has the option to tap on them. what are you actually trying to achieve, are you just trying to keep track of which checkbox was tapped ?

Comment: I am trying to disable checkboxes that were tapped and for the app to remember disabled checkboxes when it returns to this action.

Comment: then your approach is already flawed, because you make use of the same variable name inside shared prefs - `checked`. that variable is going to be used whether you have 1 or 100 checkboxes, but it isn't tied to any specific one. like i said, used a different name for every checkbox